# A proof about complex polar form

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to proof that $e^{i\theta}e^{i\phi} = e^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ as my homework using Euler's formula. And then using trigonometric sum formulas, I guess.

I would appreciate if you gave me some hints.

Comment: Have you tried expanding out both sides using Euler's formula?

Comment: I don't think I should modify both sides. I tried to expand right side and then continue with sin and cos sum formulas.
My right side so far: 
$cos(\theta)cos(\phi) - sin(\theta)sin(\phi) + i(sin(\theta)cos(\phi) + cos(\theta)sin(\phi))$

Comment: That's how you confuse yourself. Expand both sides and see what you need to change to go from one form to the other. Find trig identities that work.

Comment: I got it. I actually started with left side and ended up with right side using identities "backwards".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
e^{it} e^{is} &= (\cos{s} + i \sin s) (\cos t + i \sin{t}) \\
&= (\cos{s} \cos{t} - \sin{s} \sin{t}) + i (\sin s \cos t + \sin t \cos s)
\end{align}

Now use the identities

$$\cos{(s + t)} = \cos{s} \cos{t} - \sin{s} \sin{t}$$

and

$$\sin{(s + t)} = \sin s \cos t + \sin t \cos s$$